# UI elements do not get a new look after upgrade the API level to 14 (ICS)

Tags: android, api, version

I have an android project and originally set its target API to 2.3.3. Recently, I want to update the target API to ICS (API Version 14).

I did the following:

- update the android:minSdkVersion to version 14.
- Change the Project Android Properties (Right click on the project->Properties->Select Google APIs 14).

After a clean and rebuild, the ui elements (button, edit text) still has the old 2.3.3 looks and not the 4.0 looks.

Any thought on what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Holo theme to your Android Manifest in the activity tag.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

Comment: thanks. i end up putting it in the <application> tag because i want that theme for the entire application.